# Лишний хеш при редиректе PHP

Tags: php, header

При получении данных из форы я делаю редирект на определенный адрес, но в итоге меня перенаправляет на нужный мне адрес и в конце ставится `#`

`header("Location: https://google.as/");` в итоге меня перенаправит на https://google.as/#

Как убрать этот хеш на конце? Понятно, что в action  у меня стоит #, пустоту я ведь не поставлю.